# CSS directory issue?

Tags: css

Let's say if I link to a background img in a css file `url(img/bg.png)`, and the css file is at http://example.com/test/style.css and the img file is at http://example.com/test/img/bg.png

However I browse the page at http://example.com/index.html and i like to the css file via `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='test/style.css' />` with the base set to `<base href="http://example.com" />`

Would the css file work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

index.html includes test/style.css , which is a valid link

AND

style.css has `/test/` as root so img/bg.png is also valid link

**NOTE:** as a general convention it's good to include `./` when referring to current directory best choice is to refer images like `./test/bg.png` from your css file

Comment: Conflicting answers? See answer by Surreal

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to)

Comment: I was wrong, had it backwards in my head. The accepted answer explains it very nicely.