# asp.net background-image control

Tags: asp.net, background-image

When I put background-image: url() in to .css , browser doesnt put that image in that postition, but when i write that command in .aspx i get the image. Why it cant to call image from .css , i am making few themes so i have in every theme one .css and in each i want to have other header pict for example.

Comment: Is the image from the css not being found?  Or just being positioned incorrectly?  Can you include some of your css/markup?

Comment: not found
#header
{
 background-image:url(pict/logo.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `pict/logo.jpg` in your .css file, this is relative to the location of the .css file, not the file it's included in.  If you put it in your .aspx, it's relative to the .aspx.  You probably just need `/pict/logo.jpg`

See this previous question:

[Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to#940475)