# How to use relative/absolute paths in css URLs?

Tags: css, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a production and development server.
The problem is the directory structure.

Development:

- `http://dev.com/subdir/images/image.jpg`
- `http://dev.com/subdir/resources/css/style.css`

Production:

- `http://live.com/images/image.jpg`
- `http://live.com/resources/css/style.css`

How can I have a `style.css` in `css` folder that uses on both servers the same path for the `background: url` property? Is there a trick I can use with relative paths?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The URL is [relative to the location of the CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940451/7586), so this should work for you:

```
url('../../images/image.jpg')
```

The relative URL goes two folders back, and then to the `images` folder - it should work for both cases, as long as the structure is the same.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#url:

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document

Comment: will this work If I have to go 2 steps back ( updated the answer ) url(../../images/image.jpg) ?

Comment: @anothershrubery - sorry my first example was flawed

Comment: @danip - it should work, but you don't have two steps from `http://domain.com/css/style.css`. I'm not sure what can be done there... **EDIT:** - yes, it should work with the updated structure, I've updated the answer (just another `../`, it seems).

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I would fix this in the .htaccess file.  You should have access to that.

Define your CSS URL as such:

```
url(/image_dir/image.png);
```

In your .htacess file, put:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^image_dir/(.*) subdir/images/$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^image_dir/(.*) images/$1
```

depending on the site.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem... every time that i wanted to publish my css.. I had to make a search/replace.. and relative path wouldnt work either for me because the relative paths were different from dev to production.

Finally was tired of doing the search/replace and I created a dynamic css, (e.g. www.mysite.com/css.php) it's the same but now i could use my php constants in the css. somethig like

```
.icon{
  background-image:url('<?php echo BASE_IMAGE;?>icon.png');
}
```

and it's not a bad idea to make it dynamic because now i could compress it using YUI compressor without loosing the original format on my dev server.

Good Luck!

Comment: There is no `php` tag on the question! OP might be not using php at all.

Comment: is just an exemple.. you could use php, asp, jsp.. the idea is the same

Comment: it could also be static.

Comment: Also if this is in a CSS file then the `<?php **** ?>` wont be processed