# CSS/Javascript Testing Issues

Tags: php, css, apache

Okay, this is a little lengthy, but here's the issue...

I am testing an Apache 2.4.3 webserver, running PHP 5.4.11 and I'm running into issues on some pages displaying the css menu and javascript.  Let me say that I am not the webpage designer,  just the server minion... The developer has used both absolute paths, and relative paths on different pages to call the css and javascript.  When testing, the pages that use the absolute path do not display the css menu, nor run the javascript, but the pages with relative paths do.  To possibly complicate matters, I am running two name based virtual hosts on the server, the issue only manifesting itself only on Domain1, the secondary domain doesn't utilize these features.  When testing it happens when I am on the server using the localhost, or from a laptop with the domains defined in the host file.  I'm not sure if it is an issue with the way I am testing the site, or the configuration of the site, or a combination of the two.  The css calls, and configuration files are as follows:

---

css call from webpage that works:

```
<link href="../css/cu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

file is located:  Document Root/domain1/Folder1/index.php

---

css call from webpage that doesn't work:

```
<link href="http://www.domain1/css/cu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <style type="text/css">
```

file is located:  Document Root/domain1/index.php (domain1 main webpage)

---

httpd-vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.domain1.com
DocumentRoot "/Document Root/domain1"
ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /Server Root/cgi-bin/
ErrorDocument 404 /domain1/error/404.php
ErrorLog logs/domain1-error_log
CustomLog logs/domain1-access_log common

<Directory "/var/www/html/domain1">
AllowOverride All 
Options FollowSymLinks 
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/Document Root/domain1/images">
AllowOverride All 
Options FollowSymLinks 
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/Document Root/domain1/includes">
AllowOverride All 
Options All
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/Document Root/domain1/css">
AllowOverride All 
Options All
Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.domain2.com
DocumentRoot "/Document Root/domain2/cuss"
ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com
ErrorDocument 404 /domain2/error/404.php
ErrorLog logs/domain2-error_log
CustomLog "logs/domain2-access_log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

---

.htaccess file:  file located: Document Root/domain1/

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^faq.php http://www.domain1/faq [L]

CheckSpelling on
```

---

host file on server:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.domain    localhost
:1  www.domain1.com localhost6.domain   localhost6
<server ip address> www.domain1.com
<server ip address> www.domain2.com
```

---

host file on testing laptop:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
<server ip address> www.domain1.com
<server ip address> www.domain2.com
```

I need to get this server into production ASAP!   Does anyone have any ideas on how to test this to be confident that it will all work correctly when it goes live?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the same question here: [How to use relative/absolute paths in css URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815452/how-to-use-relative-absolute-paths-in-css-urls)

I think you just need to change production link to:

```
<link href="css/cu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Because **css** folder and **index** file are on the same level.

Comment: I changed the file on the fly and it still doesn't work.  This same website is running on an existing production server, and it works fine.  I've copied it's configuration, the only difference is that the new one is a vhost, and the production is a standalone site.

Comment: But it shouldn't matter where and how it's hosted. Maybe you can check from where it tries to load the css file? 
[Chrome networking tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console/)

Comment: I may be barking up the wrong tree.  I guess I should be working on making the Apache server configuration work with the pages, instead of the other way around.

Comment: I've decided that the best way to remedy this issue, since I cannot find a server side resolution is to have the web designer change their code to use relative paths.  Thanks to all who tried to help.