# background-image: url() is not loading image from css file

Tags: css

I'm using XAAMP server for development
I'm trying to crate a parallax effect but the image home_image.png is not accessible from index.css.
I tried both ways from below but none of them are working.
[Folder structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdMmf.png)
[Added image local path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNUmQ.png)
[Network console path trying to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK6np.png)

```css
.img-1{
    background-image: url('/healtech/assets/images/home_image.png');
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.img-2{
    background-image: url('../images/home_image.png');
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-1"></div>
<div class="img-2"></div>
```

I tried to create parallax effect but background image is not accessible from index.css :

Comment: Where is the html file in the file tree?

Comment: `/healtech/assets/images/home_image.png` means the path from the root (path from domain name) because it starts with a / slash.

Comment: could you open home_image.png in the browser and send  a screenshot ?

Comment: added image local path , please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe that Your URL address is not correctly linked to the pictures!
You can use a relative path to fix this issue. For Example :

[How to use relative/absolute paths in css URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815452/how-to-use-relative-absolute-paths-in-css-urls)

if you are defined this CSS class in your Index.css this will work correctly

```
background-image: url('../images/home_image.png');
```

Comment: I have added the screenshot . it's index.php file

Comment: I tried with relative url w.r.t. index.css but not working

Comment: Please see img-2 class where I tried with relative url ,but no luck.