# absolute positioning in a relative div overlaps the following div

Tags: css

I can't understand why a `div` positioned as `absolute` inside a `relative` `div` overlaps other elements. As far as I can understand, its position should be fix in its `relative` `div` container and encompassed in it, shouldn't it?

My attempt:

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="before">
  some div
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="after">
  other div
</div>
```

I wonder why `#content`, positioned as `relative`, overlaps `#after`.

Comment: When you position an element absolutely you are taking it out of the normal document flow. It is positioned relative to the body element in your example, of which `#content` is a child of. The real question is: what are you trying to achieve visually?

Comment: @Terry, thanks for your answer. In fact, this is a theoretical question for my own knowledge, relative to the first answer I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76323332/4698373). Could `sticky` make the job if I wanted to shift the image in it's parent without breaking the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning from MDN docs,

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. It is [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#types_of_positioning) relative
> to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed
> relative to the initial [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block). Its final position is
> determined by the values of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`.
>
> This value creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context) when the value of `z-index` is
> not `auto`. The margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not [collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_box_model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)
> with other margins.

If you want to maintain the flow then you need to remove `position: relative` from the parent.

Generally if you want child elements to be positioned relative to its current position without changing the layout around it, you apply `position: relative` on child.

Applying `position: absolute` places the child relative to the parent's position, changing the layout around it.

```css
#content {
  background: red;
}

#overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="before">
  some div
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
    <div>Some text.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="after">
  other div
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, I have edited my question to apply your answer. :)

Comment: @Philippe don't do this. A question needs to remain a *question*. It should not contain an answer