# stylesheet url not loading properly

Tags: html, css, url, include, directory

so evidently according to this [Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to), css that is loaded from the link tag references files in relation to the folder that the css file is in...

so here's my directory structure:

```
httpdocs/
     css/
         thecss.css
         bg.png
```

so thecss.css contains the following entry

```
#guinea {background-image:url(bg.png)}
```

but the problem is...the image is not showing up even though it's in the exact same directory with the css....

on the other hand if I change it to this:

```
#guinea {background-image:url(http://localhost/css/bg.png)}
```

it would work!

using url(/css/bg.php) doesn't work either...

what am I doing wrong? why is my relative url include not working?

Comment: Odd. What happens if you do #guinea {background-image:url(/css/bg.png)}?

Comment: This should work.  I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: Even though your method should work, try `background: url('bg.png');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it's best to separate your images and your styles.

So place your `bg.png` in an `images` folder and reference it as so...

`#guinea {background-image:url(../images/bg.png)}`

Comment: even thought that it is true, it is not a fix to the problem.