# How to write css in MVC (asp.net) for the application who goes in directory of domain and root?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

i want to set a background image in a application and image goes in my application is

application /images/ --> images is here

but when application hosted the background image not worked because path i given based on current settings who broken when application hosted in subdomain.

how i can set it dynamically

Answer (score 2):

You use relative paths in a .css file, they are relative to the location of the stylesheet, not the location of the current page:-

```
a.external
{
  background-image:url('external-link.gif');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

will look for an image called 'external-link.gif' in the same directory as the .css file.

So if your directory structure looks like:-

- {Domain Root}
- Content
- Content\Style.css
- Images
- Images\MyImage.png

you could reference MyImage.png from Style.css with:-

```
url('../Images/MyImage.png')
```

Then if you moved your application into a subdirectory:-

- {Domain Root}
- Site
- Site\Content
- Site\Content\Style.css
- Site\Images
- Site\Images\MyImage.png

The same url ('../Images/MyImage.png') still finds the image because the *relative* path *between* the two resources has not changed.

See also:

- [Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to)

Comment: but application goes in sob-domain means broken the URL of image.

Comment: Not if you use a relative URL like I just described! The URLs in my post are relative to the location of the .css file. Edited my post.