# How to use background image in CSS?

Tags: java, css

I am using the background image in my application in CSS . I am using the following code to get the background image file

```
background-image: url("Image\GREEN.GIF");
```

but I am not able to get the Image .. I know that it is path problem .. I can able to get the 
absolute path in java using

```
path=new File("web/CSS/myimage.gif").getAbsolutePath();
```

but in CSS how to get the absolute path..

please help me in getting the absolute path in CSS

Thanks in Advance

Raj

Comment: Why are you mixing CSS, Java, JavaScript? What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to get the absolute path via CSS, but can you not use relative paths here?

Say you have the following:

```
-root
-----css
-----img
```

In order to then reference your images from you css file, you would simply put a path of

```
background-image: url("../img/myfile.gif");
```

Comment: Thanks .. it is working .. But my doubt is if I deploy the war file in tomcat webapps folder , is it work?

Comment: You should be ok because the path to your image will be relative to the folder you css resides in. Assuming you keep the folder structure the same in your deployment environment and you're not using some form of URL rewriting which interferes, you should be ok.

Answer (score 5):

```
url("Image\GREEN.GIF")
```

should be

```
url("Image/GREEN.GIF")
```

Relative URLs should work perfectly well in CSS, so you don't need absolute URLs.  Just be aware that some URLs are [relative to the stylesheet, not the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to) that loads it.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that the item your giving the background image to must have content in it, or set dimensions! Otherwise nothing will show!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need absolute URLs.Normally,the urls in stylesheet are relative to the stylesheet,but if you define the mouse cursor's  image,URLs relative to the stylesheet are not supported by IE,you should set the path relative to root path or use absolute path.