# background html image

Tags: html, image

I'd like to make an image the background of one of my html pages.

I tried

```
body
{
background-image:url('./images/backgroundimage.gif');
}
```

But this wouldn't make it appear as the background image. I feel like this should be working, but it isn't. Anyone have better ideas, or see what I have wrong with this idea?

Comment: Have you checked the dimensions of body...sometimes when the page is positioned absolute, the body does not have any height...so the background image would not be visible

Comment: that doesn't look like a valid path. Either start with a double dot, /, or just "images...". Each of those means something different relative or absolute to the file though.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the single quotes and the `./`

Also, make sure that file actually exists relative to the that **css file**'s url.

Edit: [also search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `background-image:url(../Images/backgroundimage.gif);` and as **bkconrd** suggestion, make sure your image file located in correct path(I assume you ain't newbie in HTML, hope you check your directory structure). you can Use inline css too 
 `<body STYLE="background-image: url(../images/backgroundimage.gif)"></body>`
(for testing purpose, But usage of Inline Style generally not recommended style of coding).

Hope this helps you, If not let us know .... Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this. I think this will work because I have tested it.

```
body {
    background:url('./images/backgroundimage.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```