# Symfony2 is trying to feed my /css/* paths through routing but I don't want it to

Tags: routes, symfony

If I go to this URI

```
/app_dev.php/css/eabd201_jquery.ui.theme_15.css
```

it gives me that CSS file, which is what I would expect, but if I go to this URI,

```
/app_dev.php/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
```

I get this error:

> No route found for "GET /css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png"

It seems like there must be a way to tell Symfony not to try to go through routing for `/css/*` paths. (I know the file exists.) How might I do that?

Edit: here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you're using Apache, paste your `web/.htaccess` file; if you're using nginx, paste your vhost config. Also paste your `security.yml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's exactly your case but imagine the directory structure:

```
├── css
│   ├── style.css
├── images
│   ├── foo.png
```

In `style.css`, as soon as you are referencing your images using relative paths like `url(../images/foo.png)`, so it can't work if you move `style.css` into another directory.

You're using Assetic to render your CSS files so assetic "moves" this CSS file into the `/app_dev.php/css` directory which does not really exist and is handled by the `app_dev.php` controller. So now, the relative path to the image does not point to the image but to `/app_dev.php/images/foo.png` which also does not really exist and is handled by the `app_dev.php` controller.

Hopefully it's a really common problem and there is a built-in solution: the `cssrewrite` filter.

You can either add it to your `{% stylesheet %}` tags:

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
    # ...
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

```
{# your template #}

{% stylesheet 'bundles/foo/css/style.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
```

Or apply it to every CSS file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
    # ...
    filters:
        cssrwrite:
            apply_to: \.css$
```

It will take care of rewriting this kind of paths for your.

Comment: I tried both methods you suggested. The second one didn't seem to work but the first one did.