# Hard coded URLs in CSS file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc

The project I'm working on has hard coded URLs in the CSS file like this:

```
a.edit
{
    background: url(/TestSite/Images/Edit.png) no-repeat top left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    padding:1px;
    margin:1px;
    text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}
```

When the site is moved to production, these links break.  I'm looking for a solution so it just works where ever the site is run.

This is what I came up with and it works but I'm wondering if there is a better way:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.edit").css('background', 'url(' + $("body").data("baseurl") + 'Images/Edit.png) no-repeat top left');
    });
</script>
<body data-baseurl="~/">...</body>
```

Comment: Why not work with relative urls?

Comment: What is the URL structure of the pages themselves? If the pages are under `/TestSite/` then I don't see why you would include this in the css URL

Comment: @BrianWarshaw, care to elaborate why you consider this to be a great question?

Comment: Won't relative URLs break if the CSS file is used from a URL that isn't in the same "directory"?

Comment: I wonder if there's a way in MVC to do what you might do in PHP in this case--point to a PHP file for the CSS and have some processing for determining your environment.

Comment: I tried relative paths but I didn't realize it was relative to the CSS file.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @walther Because I, like the OP, didn't realize that the paths in a CSS file were relative to the CSS file--I assumed that they were relative to the html source referencing the css file.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw, that, sir, would be a nightmare :)

Comment: Indeed it would--my focus has shifted largely to desktop apps since being a web developer years ago, so I done forgot :-)

Of course, you could always serve stylesheets as from a controller action, and store the stylesheet in a Razor view with rules. But I would totally agree that for his specific case, that just ain't necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS handles relative URLS relative to where the stylesheet is located. Take advantage of that and don't rewrite URLs in javascript.

Comment: Bingo.  I tried relative paths but I didn't realize it was relative to the CSS file.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Use on production and development server the same folder structure. And use relative paths

Comment: Good answer but unfortunately it’s not under my control.  It is a corporate environment and both sides would squak if I tried to change either.

Comment: @tzerb I don't know about it. But you can try to use relative paths relatively to `base meta` tag. and display different `base` to production and development server

Answer (score 2):

Don't really understand what's the problem you're facing. Use relative paths instead of absolute and you will be fine no matter the hosting provider...

Btw, one more thing to consider - what if the client turns off javascript? ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about a [relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to)?

```
a.edit
{
    background: url(Images/Edit.png) no-repeat top left;
    ...
}
```