# Windows 8 - Use image for background

Tags: css, windows, html, windows-8, winjs

I'm creating my first Windows 8 app and I have a problem with CSS!

I have a folder `images` and background texture `bg.png` inside it. Also, stylesheet is in `css` folder.

**CSS**:

```
#contenthost {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("../images/bg.png") repeat;
}
```

But nothing happen! I tried `background: #999` which works. What should I do?

Comment: Did you checked your Image path?

Comment: As already answered on SO, URLs in CSS are relative to the CSS file, not to the HTML document http://stackoverflow.com/a/940475/268

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example with path to the image relative to the app root and it worked without any issues:

```
#contenthost {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('/images/logo.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

In terms of your code this would be:

```
#contenthost {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('/images/bg.png') repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not the path (using absolute vs. relative as above would fix that) you also need to make sure you have an element with an id = contenthost.

CSS let's you do both id and classes so if you start getting into styling page controls you will see a heavy use of classes like (.mypage .subsection).

Finally, you can always set the background in any individual html file directly on the body tag like:

```
        <body style="background-image: url('/images/bg.png');">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also save the image in your project folder. 
And load it in the html page like this:

```
<img id="mainImg2" src="ms-appdata:///Local//bckgrnd.jpg" />
```