# pie.htc not fixing css3 issues

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, css3pie

I have the PIE.HTC in the root directory and trying to make rounded corners work in Internet Explorer

This is my CSS

```
#credits-earned
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:#EDEDED;
    width:170px;
    height:60px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius:8px;
    behavior: url (PIE.htc);
}
```

The HTML this is trying to take effect on is:

```
<div id="credits-earned">
                        You need to earn X<br> more credits today to avoid losing credits
                    </div>
```

However the rounded corners are not working in IE.

Any help be appreciated.

Comment: did you include the PIE.js file the head of document? Also PIE.htc is relative to the file not the css

Comment: open a new tab and go to your_domain/pie.htc. does it load the file?

Comment: @EricLemos Lemos CSS3PIE doesn't require any js files - http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

when including a resource in a external css file the URL is relative to the css file.

if you want to include something from a different directory you could use a relative path (example `behavior:url('../PIE.htc')`) or use a absolute path (example `behavior:url('/PIE.htc')`)

for more on path's in stylesheets - [Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the proper path for pie.htc to work, give:

```
 #credits-earned
 { position: relative;
 }
```