# CSS Images In another Folder

Tags: html, css

I added the images into the folder called "images" and CSS to folder called "css", now I want to use the images in "images" folder. How do I do this? When I used this, they didn't show up:

```
background: url('/images/bg.jpg');
```

I also tried these:

```
background: url('../images/bg.jpg');
background: url('../../images/bg.jpg');
```

What is the path I should be using to access my images?

Comment: Are `images` and `css` folders at the same level?

Comment: is image folder in the same working directory? I mean is image folder and currentpage.css(the page in which you are using above code ) in same folder?

Comment: Did you try `images/bg.jpg`?

Comment: Here is the same question answerd [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to) . i hope it helps

Comment: If both folders are on the same level, use ../images.

Comment: Hey, did you find a better answer, than share or accept one of these. THX

Answer (score 22):

If you have a folder structure like follows:

```
/public_html/
    /css/
    /images/
    /index.html
```

Then your CSS should work.

> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts    there (and so on...) To move forward, just start with the first
>     subdirectory and keep moving forward

Read more here: http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Answer (score 2):

Here is the same question answerd [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-l‌​ocation-is-it-relative-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-l%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bocation-is-it-relative-to).

here is the W3C spec from the answer http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url

With other words it depences on the Folder Structur, as commented under your Post, by **Sport Billy**.

i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

When you use background-images, make sure you give width and height too for the container containing the images.

Comment: Is this an answer for the problem? Maybe just a tip.

Comment: It is an answer. Not a tip. I am sure you haven't faced this issue.

Comment: The question here is about folders, not best (correct) practices. That's what I meant.

Comment: It is not only suggesting the correct practice, but is answering to the problem of the OP which is that the background image not being displayed. He says that he tried different approaches and none worked,  so it might be because he has not specified width and height.

Comment: @Sport Billy +1 because you are right. I personally would have written this in the comment section of the question, but it is a vaild answer.