# Image not loading on when html directly opened

Tags: html, css

My project fetches the background images when i run it using brackets, however it doesn't load when i directly open it from  the directory  and neither when i upload it to the server

Html code

```
<header>
        <div class="header-logo"></div>
            <nav class="nav clearfix">
                <ul> 
                <li><a class="active" href="#">LOGIN</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
```

css:

```
.header-logo

{
 width:20%;
 background-image: url('/images/logo.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:80px; 
float:left;
}
```

This is my directory structure :

[image]

Comment: if the style in css file and the file in the css folder then your url should be url(../images/logo.png);

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Images In another Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785390/css-images-in-another-folder)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test such problems is just editing CSS rule in Firebug (or similar tool). You can edit path there and check in which situations it is working. You did not write anything about domain mapping - or is just simple opened local HTML page?

Comment: actually i had specified the wrong path , brackets that simply internally referenced the image as(/images/logo.png) so when i went to just open the page from the desktop  locally it didnt load , after correcting the path to (../images/logo.png) everything is working fine even on the server