# Img Swap with CSS won't work

Tags: html, css

Here is my code.
HTML:

```
<div id="socmed">

<div id="icons"> 
    <div id="fb"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#socmed {
height: 100px;
padding-top: 70px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
background-color:rgba(247, 34, 34, 0.7);
width: 100%;
}

#icons {
width: 300px;
height: 75px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

#fb {
height: .89in;
width: .89in;
background-image:url("../images/facebook_dark.png");
}
#fb:hover {
height: .89in;
width: .89in;
background-image:url("../images/facebook_active.png");
```

Currently, neither logo shows up in my "socmed" div. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Stumped.

Comment: when you use `inspect element` what you get?

Comment: The path to the images are relative to the CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to

Comment: so currently my directory looks like this. style.css>>>CSS>>>index.html>>>IMAGES>>>facebook_active.png

Comment: Am i simply linking it wrong?

Comment: Check the image contain folder path

Answer (score 0):

check the following steps:

1.Image contains folder path (`inspect the path`)
2.If  image size is big it won't appear full image.so it will appear partial image according the  mentioned dimension.for that problem use `background-size` property

Take a look :[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/ZSgkb/)