# Can't put image behind text in html and css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello1
I'm working with a html and css project. I want to create a box for text which has an image in background like in this image:
[image]
The result I get is this:
[image]

```css
.background {
  background: url(background.png) repeat;
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: sepia(100%);
}
div.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

  <div class="transbox">
    <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there something I should change in my code? My image `background.png` exists in the folder where I have the html file. Thanks!

Comment: Is the CSS file in the same folder the html file exists? Do you use css file or direct style tag?

Comment: just tested, your code is fine, check whether your 'background.png' exists in the same folder

Comment: For sure, you have problem with the path. Tell us what is the folder/file structure of html,css,image files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use this in your css file:

```
background: url(background.png) repeat;
```

That means the image is in the same folder as the css file.

if the image is in a folder upper of the css file, use this"

```
background: url('../background.png') repeat;
```

Also, if you are trying on a Linux OS, care about the upper/lower cases of name of files

Thanks @StephenP for putting the complete message:

paths in CSS files are relative to the style sheet, not relative to the document

Comment: I think you should explicitly state this rule in your answer: "`url()` paths in CSS files are relative to the style sheet, not relative to the document"_ — [from the W3 as cited in another SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/940475/17300)

Comment: @StephenP, I meant what you said. But, your message is more clear. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

if your file structure looks like this:

```
index.html
css/style.css
img/background.png
```

you should link to background like this: `url('../img/background.png')`
".." will go back to parent folder

https://jsfiddle.net/cnLjf8e5/

Answer (score 0):

The main problem could be this

```
  background: url(background.png) repeat;
```

System can't find this picture, try it like this

```
background-image: url("background.png") repeat;
```

And be sure, that this image is in this location

Comment: It still doesnt work. Yes the background.png image is in the same folder as the html file but not the css file

Comment: And if you change 100% to some pixels? If that doesn't work try this `background: url("background.png") repeat !important;`

Comment: @Kyrgios ... it's still not going to work by specifying pixels. Mojtaba's answer is correct — the path given in a `url(...)` within a CSS file is a path _relative to the CSS file location._