# Django/Mezzanine: CSS "@import url()" not work properly

Tags: python, html, css, django, mezzanine

I have built the default mezzanine site.
However, in the admin page of the site, only part of the styles are applied to the site.
And I see some error logs

```
[18/Apr/2017 00:03:47] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4251
[18/Apr/2017 00:03:47] "GET /static/grappelli/css/base.css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 4
04 1709
[18/Apr/2017 00:03:47] "GET /static/grappelli/css/base.css/typography.css HTTP/1
.1" 404 1724
[18/Apr/2017 00:03:48] "GET /static/grappelli/css/base.css/modules.css HTTP/1.1"
 404 1715
[18/Apr/2017 00:03:48] "GET /static/grappelli/css/base.css/tables.css HTTP/1.1"
404 1712
[18/Apr/2017 00:03:48] "GET /static/grappelli/css/base.css/forms.css HTTP/1.1" 4
04 1709
[18/Apr/2017 00:03:48] "GET /static/grappelli/css/base.css/widgets.css HTTP/1.1"
 404 1715
[18/Apr/2017 00:03:48] "GET /static/grappelli/css/base.css/webkit-gradients.css
HTTP/1.1" 404 1742
[18/Apr/2017 00:03:48] "GET /static/grappelli/css/img/grappelli-icon.png HTTP/1.
1" 404 1721
```

It seems paths of some css files are wrong.
The path shouldn't be /static/grappelli/css/base.css/xxxx.css but /static/grappelli/css/xxxx.css

When I dig into the /static/grappelli/css/base.css file, I see this file imports those wrong path css files like this

```
...
@import url('reset.css');
@import url('typography.css');
@import url('modules.css');
@import url('tables.css');
@import url('forms.css');
@import url('widgets.css');
...
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on the latest sources. According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/940475/1938621), those `url()`'s should be resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04.3 with python3.5.1. This is an issue that has be noted in mezzanine bugs but I couldn't find a workaround.

I upgraded to ubuntu 17.04 with python3.5.3 and there was no issue, some deep dark magic is happening in grappelli here.