# CSS: How to set background image which will fit to screen?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am working on my website, I already added some images and now I want to set one background, main, which will be covered by the others, is it possible?

Entering `background-image:url("myphoto.jpg")` does not work for me. any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: can you provide us some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)

Comment: use `background-size:cover` property

Comment: I believe the issue is caused by the CSS file being in a different folder and needing a different relative path to the image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to

Answer (score 1):

Give background class to the dive in which you want to apply background image. and give css as per below:
    This is how you can do:

```
    <div class="background"></div>

and style css would be:

.background{
background: url("myphoto.jpg") no-repeat center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   body {
      background: url("myphoto.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: @Luigi, the image url must be relative to the CSS file. For example, if your CSS file is in a subfolder relative to the html file, you may need to change the path to something like this: url("../myphoto.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

@Hiren is correct, but you need to "Locate" the desired image, fx. if we say i have my www folder wich is my main folder, i have an index.html and a sub-folder called IMG, and inside there i got myphoto.jpg

then the following should be set as the url: `url("img/myphoto.jpg")`

```css
body {
      background: url("https://www.qdtricks.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/hd-road-wallpaper.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  background: url("{{asset('staticImage/wallpapers/wall_num10.jpg')}}") no-repeat center center fixed !important;

        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
```