# background image url doesn't find img folder in laravel

Tags: css, image, laravel

In my style file, I have a background with a url that links to my image. But the image doesn't display on screen..

So, I have my image saved in:

> public/img/coding.jpeg

And my Sass file saved in:

> resources/assets/sass/style.scss

I have tried this code in my Sass file:

```
background: url("/public/img/coding.jpeg");
```

But that doesn't work. Why not..

Comment: Are you seeing a 404 in your inspector for this image?  If so you're path to the image is incorrect.  If it's 200, then you have a display issue, probably CSS. If 'public' is the actual html root directory, then your path should start with /img

Comment: Yes I see a 404 error, but the problem is, the path is correct. This is the URL: http://mark.dev/public/img/coding.jpeg and there is no folder before public.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you apply it to the body in your CSS? :)

```
body {
      background: url("/public/img/coding.jpeg");
}
```

you can also just apply it directly to your body tag...

```
<body background="/public/img/coding.jpeg"> 
</body>
```