# CSS background-image does not load

Tags: css

I'm currently making a website in PHP. When developing it I use xampp (localhost), and the pictures are visible.

```
<div data-bs-parallax-bg="true" style="height:500px;background-image:url(&quot;assets/img/mypicture.jpg&quot;);background-position:center;background-size:cover;">
```

When I wanted to upload to web server the pictures are invisible.

I tried these options but still not working.

```
style="height:500px;background-image:url('assets/img/mypicture.jpg');

style="height:500px;background-image:url('./assets/img/mypicture.jpg');

style="height:500px;background-image:url('../assets/img/mypicture.jpg');

style="height:500px;background-image:url('https:/example.com/assets/img/mypicture.jpg');
```

and the same with only `background:url();`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes (single, double).

`background-image: url(assets/img/mypicture.jpg);`

Also, be careful when using relative paths here. Check this question too:

[Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to)

Comment: What is the full URL of your document, and what is the URL of your image?

Comment: I typed in my image URL path and 403 forbidden

Comment: @v1kt0r81 Well that might explain... :)