# Can't get @font-face to work Is there a problem with the path?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to get the font-face to work but can't seem to change the font family. This is what I have. 
I downloaded panton as a folder and transferred four files 
into assests/fonts but it still doesn't show up?
Thanks in advance

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'panton';
  src: url('assests/fonts/Panton-BlackCaps.otf'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('assests/fonts/Panton-BlackitalicCaps.otf') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('assests/fonts/Panton-LightCaps.otf') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('assests/fonts/Panton-LightitalicCaps.otf') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */

}
```

Comment: `assests` is mispelled. Also, check your browser's network tab. What kind of response are you getting when requesting for those font files?

Comment: Note that the URLs you've used are [relative to the CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to).

Comment: Oh yes how silly of me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(resolved in comments, answer added for completeness)

Relative paths in CSS as used here [are always interpreted relative to the source of the CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to).