# .Net Core Spa Resource Routing on Relative paths

Tags: asp.net-core, url-routing, single-page-application, middleware, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following .net core spa application configured

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "catch",
                template: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "Spa";
            spa.Options.DefaultPage = "/home/index";
        });
    }
```

Everything works well except for the fact that images and other static resources are accessed relatively to the initial url instead of the root.

eg When my initial url is https://localhost:44380/, images are correctly fetched from https://localhost:44380/.

[image]

However when my initial url is https://localhost:44380/administration/user-profiles, images are incorrectly fetch from: https://localhost:44380/administration/.
[image]

I am not able to change the css as its a 3rd party library. Hence I would like to just route all resource files to the root url.

**Edit:** 
Here is the css of that "x"

```
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close {
    background: url("chosen-sprite.png") right top no-repeat;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 4px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 12px;
    cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: Can you give screenshots of the inspected UI code?

Comment: Show us some code from View to see how you display images

Comment: It's not the startup code who's requesting images. You should be sowing how you compose those image routes on the client.

Comment: I edited the post, however I am thinking if all images can be routed to a single controller then 1 could inspect the url and just return the correct image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually this did the trick

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();  

        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Path)))
            {
                context.Request.Path = Invariant($"/{System.IO.Path.GetFileName(context.Request.Path)}");
            }
            return next();
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use ~/ to refer to the root directory in other words https://localhost:44380

Answer (score -1):

It's the **browser's default behaviour**

You're using a relative path on your css

```
background: url("chosen-sprite.png") right top no-repeat;
```

as per specification:

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document

so if your stylesheet is loading from `https://localhost:44380/administration/` (you can check it on devtools network panel) the browser will try to load the image from there.

There's more info regarding this issue in this [stack overflow question that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to)

Comment: Obviously... As I said I cannot change the 3rd party library hence I need some handler that can intercept all static file requests and reroute them.