# React CSS cannot access images in public folder

Tags: css, reactjs

This is a bit of a weird one.

I'm working on a React app, and have some images in the `public` folder:

```
my-app/public/images {images in here}
```

And sure enough, in my React component I can access the images:

```
 <img src='/images/img-1.jpg' />
```

I can also bring up the image in my browser:

```
 http://localhost:3000/images/img-1.jpg
```

So far, so good.

But here is the weird bit...

In my CSS if I do `background-image: url('/images/img-1.jpg');` I get: `Error: Can't resolve '/images/img-1.jpg`.

I've tried `images/img-1.jpg`, `../images/img-1.jpg`, `/public/images/img-1.jpg` and all attempts result in the same error.

I've resolved it my creating a copy of the images in:

```
 /src/src-images/...
```

And this works, but it means I have to have images in two locations. This can't be right:

```
background-image: url('src-images/img-1.jpg'}); // For CSS

<img src='/images/img-1.jpg' />  // For component
```

Does anyone know what either I am doing wrong, or do images have to be in two folders?!?

BTW, if I put the images only within the `src` folder the the Component code cannot access them!!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is the stylesheet located? If you provide a relative URL for the image, it will be relative to the stylesheet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to)