# I am attempting to link a css file to a https

Tags: css, url, hyperlink

So my client insists I have to link the logo and images through a CSS sheet, But the site isn't live or uploaded so how will the website see the linked objects like this.

Example:

```
background: url("https://mysamplesite/assets/image/header/bullet_mobile_subsmenu.png") left center no-repeat;
```

Logic tells me that it needs to read:

```
background: url("image/header/bullet_mobile_subsmenu.png") left center no-repeat;
```

But it isn't a URL, is it? what should it say instead of URL?

I know it sounds novicey... I am a novice, I do what I do and if it isn't broken I do it again and again.

Thanks all.

Comment: Hi! Did you try change absolute paths to relative? give some code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [relative URL](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/relapath.htm), which guides the browser on reaching the file relative to the current location.

If you set it inside a CSS file, make sure the path you mention is **relative to the source of the CSS file and not relative to the document** (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/940475/12595469)).

Comment: Thanks I am learning... it is all good knowledge.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer informative and helpful. Keep up the good work!