# CSS background-Image not shown in the browser

Tags: html, css, image, browser, background

I'm using Visual Studio Code. When I typed `{ background: url("big.jpeg");` in CSS style sheet my image is not shown in the live server or the browser, when typed `{ background: url("/big.jpeg"); }` image is shown in the live server but not when it is opened in the browser.
when I type`{ background: url("./big.jpeg");}` image is not shown in both live server and browser.

(image is not in a folder)

Comment: Make sure your image is in the correct location.  As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/940475/2181514) the `url(path)` is relative to the .css file.  So if you have `url("big.jpg")` then it should be in the same folder/path as the css file.  If you're not using a css file and instead have this in each page then it will need to be relative to that page (so may need multiple copies - use a single .css file).

Comment: Can you provide some code example, please? And then I think this could be pretty solvable :) 

Even screenshot would be good enough with code and image location.

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked when I put the image in the same folder as the CSS file.