# Background-image doesn't appear on the webpage

Tags: html, css, background-image

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTILu.png)
Can anyone help? Background-image doesn't appear on the page,

althouth address seem to be correct, two levels up in the folder. but still doesn't appear.

Comment: Don't share code screen shots, always share your code in text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SASS output and referenced stylesheet is /assets/sass/app.css your relative links will be relative to that, so it should be `url("../images/title-image.jpg")`  as the "sass" folder is on the same level as the "images" folder.

Reference: [Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to)

Also the parentheses are missing. Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background_image.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<div class="back-img">
</div>
```

Css:

```
.back-img {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://img-host.wemotion.co.jp/uploads/tMXOFn.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```