# Cross Browser Relative Link

Tags: cross-browser, href

I have a relative link, such as `<a href='file.ext'>text</a>`

It works fine for me, but recently we've been logging 404s on it. It seems a certain version of FF3.5 uses it as a link relative to the base domain, not the current directory (which was intended).

Can someone confirm this is a browser compatibility problem? Testing with other browsers, as well as other versions of FF seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.5 and not 3.6? I wouldn't worry about it. Might not even be a real browser. 3.5 should have auto updated to 3.6. (And 3.6 now nags users continually to upgrade to 12.)

Still, it's important to know that older versions of FF reference files a bit differently. They reference files in relation to the page. Are you sure the 404's are always in hrefs? Could they be loaded via CSS or other methods? That might explain it.

Some info here, and you'll see that the issue has changed with newer versions of FF: [Reference app relative virtual paths in .css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89418/reference-app-relative-virtual-paths-in-css-file)

You might also try using double quotes. You can download older versions (eg 3.6) of FF and test it yourself. http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-older.html

Comment: Positive. `<a href='file'>` takes him to `http://www.domain.com/file` instead of `http://www.domain.com/dir/file`, where 'dir' is the directory the referer is in.

I don't know what exaclty is happening there, it's a spcific IP, AGENT string shows FF3.5 chinese(?) build. We'll probably ignore it. Thanks!

Comment: If you've got a URL I can test, or set it up on http://jsfiddle.net/ so I can repro it, I might be able to give you an answer. But if it's only one IP that's having this issue...